# IIS 10 HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found

Tags: iis, iis-10

A few weeks ago our server hosting our IIS and everything failed. I didn't create the server but I am being tasked to work on getting everything back up and running. Previously backups weren't enabled so we lost a lot. I feel like I have everything back to where it was before but I am getting a 404 when I try to access this site from my VPN. When I click on browse localhost *.443 I can get the site to work.

Things I have tried:

- The site is started
- Bindings are what they were before
- I can access the site on my VM using the "Browse Localhost" link
- I checked network and local firewall rules and they are correct
- Downloaded "URL Rewrite" and my REGEX seems to be correct
- Anonymous Authentication is set to enabled
- Checked web.config file and from what I can tell everything is good there.

I have followed every link in Google that I can find that gives any type of help and still having this issue. But I keep getting this page.
[image]

I am at a loss and not sure what else to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: While this has nothing to do with programming, you might learn from IIS site bindings to see if any mistake was made there, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Wrong bindings prevent HTTP requests from landing on the right sites and then 404 errors are expected.

Comment: Are you using Azure VM or on-premises VM? If possible, could you please share the site bindings? What exact URL you visit in the browser? Make sure the resource you are visiting is available on your site. Are you able to access other pages of the site? If you are accessing the site from outside your network, have you configured public IP and domain name for your site?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT So you just helped me so much. I was looking at the bindings and the person who was in there before put hostname as localhost, I removed that and clicked okay. I can now access the site. So just reading your comment helped thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @Deepak-MSFT and his comment I went back and looked at the bindings, the previous person had put localhost in hostname. I just had to remove that and leave it blank and it worked!!!
[image]

Comment: thanks for posting the solution. fixed my problem too after 1 day of searching